# Access djagno model before creation one

Tags: python, django

Consider the following application structure. You have two models: Recipe and Ingredient, which are related to each other (obviously, each recipe has some ingredients and many ingredients can be in some recipes). Note, that you have decided to use M2M (many to many) relation between these two models with an explicit intermediate model -- RecipeIngredient -- which also contains one additional field named amount.

With all of the above, I have only two question for you. How would you save Recipe instance with multiple ingredients through django shell if Recipe instance still is not created. You can consider, that you already have ingredients in your DB. And the second one, how one can access amount field while creating a recipe?

If you are confused, I can reformulate the question. How you would save a recipe with specified ingredients and their amount? (If there is a way simpler model relation I can use, please, describe it).

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator


User = get_user_model()


class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='recipies',
        verbose_name='Author of a recipe'
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name of a recipe')
    image = models.ImageField()
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description of a recipe')

    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Ingredient',
        through='RecipeIngredient',
        verbose_name='Ingredients of a recipe'
    )

    cooking_time = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(44640)
        ],
        verbose_name='Cooking time in minutes'
    )

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        verbose_name='Date of creation'
    )


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name='Name of an ingredient'
    )

    measurement_unit = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        'Recipe',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(
        'Ingredient',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    amount = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(44640)
        ],
        verbose_name='Amount of ingredients'
    )
```

More formally, you have request structure described below, where id is a reference to an existing ingredient and amount is, trivially, amount of one. How should one save a recipe?

```
{

    "ingredients": [
        {
            "id": 1123,
            "amount": 10
        }
    ],
    "name": "string",
    "text": "string",
    "cooking_time": 1

}
```

Comment: Hm. That should work lazily, shouldn’t it, and cascading down, so to say? That is, `ingr = Ingredient(); rec = Recipe(); rec.ingredients.add(ingr); rec.save()` should also automatically save `ingr`. Cf. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields

Comment: For example, there are three ingredients: cheese, eggs and milk. If I wanted to fry eggs, I would create a recipe with ingredients {eggs: 4, milk: 1, cheese: 1}. As you can see three ingredients and their amount: four eggs, one glass of milk and a hunk of cheese.

Comment: The main problem here is how to save amount attribute while a recipe creation.

Comment: Your approach to the database models seems fine - can you explain more about the "main problem" above?  For example, are you trying to save these objects successively in a single view?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question - you can't. In order to add the m2m relation, you need a saved `Recipe` instance in your database with an existing ID. Only then you can add m2m relations to it. So in order to save ingredients to a `Recipe` you should do something like this:

```
some_ingredients = <Query_the_needed_ingredients_here>
recipe = Recipe.objects.create(...)
recipe.ingredients.add(*some_ingredients)
```

Reference - [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)